# show $\bar x$ is biased estimator $f(x)=e^{(\delta-x)}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

> let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be random sample from the distribution $f(x)=e^{(\delta-x)}$ for $x\geq\delta$. show $\bar x$ is biased estimator and use it to find the unbiased estimator.

**My solution**:

To show its biased:
$$E[\bar x]=E[\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i]=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[x_i]$$
$$E[x_i]=\int_{\delta}^\infty x_i e^{\delta-x_i}dx_i=1-\delta$$
Hence, $E[\bar x]=1-\delta \implies$ bias estimator.

Therefore, an unbiased estimator is $\hat \delta =1-\bar x$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Check your expectation integral . . . should be $1+\delta$

Comment: Beside the result of the integral it looks fine. $E(\overline x)=1+\delta$. Thus the unbiased estimator is $\hat \delta=\overline x-1$